# android - web browser or whatsapp click deep link to open my application but it not work as expected

Tags: android, webview

My scenario:
when user open a link (share://product/promotionDetail/gmid/ta6qlxveqfg9akxzvx6ctaqy3v743llr) from android web browser or whatsapp, I want to open the app and display the specific page in webview.
But it open the app in web browser or whatsapp itself (whatsapp show my content) instead of open my application and display the page.

How to make it works or any alternative solution? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="share" android:host="product" /> 
</intent-filter>


Intent tIntent = this.getIntent();
String action = tIntent.getAction();

if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
    Uri myURI = tIntent.getData();
    if (myURI != null) {

        List<String> params = myURI.getPathSegments();
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://"+ myURI.getHost()+"/product/"+ params.get(0)+ ".php?" + params.get(1) + "=" + params.get(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to add  android:pathPrefix="/" in intent filter defination (https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Comment: tried and not work